# How are icons added to HTML?

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to add an icon to my page but for some reason when I add the code nothing shows up

In HTML I have added this:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/yourcode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="icon"> <i class="fas fa-fire"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have also tried adding a link to the header but there's still no change

Comment: add icon to where ?

Comment: 1. did you include the icon font you are trying to use? 2. Is the icon font/corresponding css loading correctly? 3. did you check for typos in the class for your icon?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX I want to add an icon to my page before a <p> text, I have simplified what I have in my page so I don't have to add all the code

Comment: @empiric 1. No, I haven't added any icon font, how do I do that? 2. Yes 3. Yes, there's none

Comment: Your js file: yourcode.js doesn't have any source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa fa-fire"></i>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
style URL font-awesome : http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css

<p>
    <i class="fa fa-fire"></i>

</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add source code to "yourcode.js" like below:

```
"window.FontAwesomeKitConfig = {"asyncLoading":{"enabled":true},"autoA11y":{"enabled":true},"baseUrl":"https://kit-free.fontawesome.com","license":"free","method":"css","minify":{"enabled":true},"v4shim":{"enabled":false},"version":"latest"};
!function(){!function(){if(!(void 0===window.Element||"classList"in document.documentElement)){var e,t,n,i=Array.prototype,o=i.push,a=i.splice,s=i.join;r.prototype={add:function(e){this.contains(e)||(o.call(this,e),this.el.className=this.toString())},contains:function(e){return-1!=this.el.className.indexOf(e)},item:function(e){return this[e]||null},remove:function(e){if(this.contains(e)){for(var t=0;t<this.length&&this[t]!=e;t++);a.call(this,t,1),this.el.className=this.toString()}},toString:function(){return s.call(this," ")},toggle:function(e){return this.contains(e)?this.remove(e):this.add(e),this.contains(e)}},window.DOMTokenList=r,e=Element.prototype,t="classList",n=function(){return new r(this)},Object.defineProperty?Object.defineProperty(e,t,{get:n}):e.__defineGetter__(t,n)}function r(e){for(var t=(this.el=e).className.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/\s+/),n=0;n<t.length;n++)o.call(this,t[n])}}();function f(e){var t,n,i,o;prefixesArray=e||["fa"],prefixesSelectorString="."+Array.prototype.join.call(e,",."),t=document.querySelectorAll(prefixesSelectorString),Array.prototype.forEach.call(t,function(e){n=e.getAttribute("title"),e.setAttribute("aria-hidden","true"),i=!e.nextElementSibling||!e.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("sr-only"),n&&i&&((o=document.createElement("span")).innerHTML=n,o.classList.add("sr-only"),e.parentNode.insertBefore(o,e.nextSibling))})}var e,t,u=function(e){var t=document.createElement("link");t.href=e,t.media="all",t.rel="stylesheet",document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)},m=function(e){!function(e,t,n){var i,o=window.document,a=o.createElement("link");if(t)i=t;else{var s=(o.body||o.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).childNodes;i=s[s.length-1]}var r=o.styleSheets;a.rel="stylesheet",a.href=e,a.media="only x",function e(t){if(o.body)return t();setTimeout(function(){e(t)})}(function(){i.parentNode.insertBefore(a,t?i:i.nextSibling)});var l=function(e){for(var t=a.href,n=r.length;n--;)if(r[n].href===t)return e();setTimeout(function(){l(e)})};function c(){a.addEventListener&&a.removeEventListener("load",c),a.media=n||"all"}a.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("load",c),(a.onloadcssdefined=l)(c)}(e)},n=function(e,t){var n=t&&void 0!==t.autoFetchSvg?t.autoFetchSvg:void 0,i=t&&void 0!==t.async?t.async:void 0,o=t&&void 0!==t.autoA11y?t.autoA11y:void 0,a=document.createElement("script"),s=document.scripts[0];a.src=e,void 0!==o&&a.setAttribute("data-auto-a11y",o?"true":"false"),n&&(a.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute("data-auto-fetch-svg")),a.setAttribute("data-fetch-svg-from",t.fetchSvgFrom)),i&&a.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute("defer")),s.parentNode.appendChild(a)};function h(e,t){var n=t&&t.shim?e.license+"-v4-shims":e.license,i=t&&t.minify?".min":"";return e.baseUrl+"/releases/"+("latest"===e.version?"latest":"v".concat(e.version))+"/"+e.method+"/"+n+i+"."+e.method}try{if(window.FontAwesomeKitConfig){var i=window.FontAwesomeKitConfig;"js"===i.method&&(t={async:(e=i).asyncLoading.enabled,autoA11y:e.autoA11y.enabled},"pro"===e.license&&(t.autoFetchSvg=!0,t.fetchSvgFrom=e.baseUrl+"/releases/"+("latest"===e.version?"latest":"v".concat(e.version))+"/svgs"),e.v4shim.enabled&&n(h(e,{shim:!0,minify:e.minify.enabled})),n(h(e,{minify:e.minify.enabled}),t)),"css"===i.method&&function(e){var t,n,i,o,a,s,r,l,c=f.bind(f,["fa","fab","fas","far","fal"]);e.autoA11y.enabled&&(n=c,o=[],a=document,s=a.documentElement.doScroll,r="DOMContentLoaded",(l=(s?/^loaded|^c/:/^loaded|^i|^c/).test(a.readyState))||a.addEventListener(r,i=function(){for(a.removeEventListener(r,i),l=1;i=o.shift();)i()}),l?setTimeout(n,0):o.push(n),t=c,"undefined"!=typeof MutationObserver&&new MutationObserver(t).observe(document,{childList:!0,subtree:!0})),e.v4shim.enabled&&(e.asyncLoading.enabled?m(h(e,{shim:!0,minify:e.minify.enabled})):u(h(e,{shim:!0,minify:e.minify.enabled})));var d=h(e,{minify:e.minify.enabled});e.asyncLoading.enabled?m(d):u(d)}(i)}}catch(e){}}();"
```

And HTML source code like below:

```html
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
   </head>
        
   <body>
        <div class="icon"> <i class="fas fa-fire"></i></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @srinivas works if you are trying to use older version of FontAwesome but as per your initial question, if you are trying to use the FontAwesome kit then there is nothing wrong with your actual posted code. Just make  sure

1) the kit code is correct and the script is loading.

2) the icon "fa-fire" exists in the kit you have and

3) the div with class "icon" surrounding the icon is not interfering with the icons style.